# Meaning of "the couple that boops noses together in between makeout sessions and sweet nothings"

Tags: meaning

This is a sentence I've come across while reading [7 Things About Love That Make No Sense](http://thoughtcatalog.com/2013/7-things-about-love-that-make-no-sense/)

> If you’re the couple that just stands on the sidewalk for extended
>   periods of time and boops noses together in between makeout sessions
>   and sweet nothings, you deserve to get breadcrumbs thrown at you.

Is a metaphor or some rhetorical device used? Why do they deserve breadcrumbs? What are *boops noses* and *sweet nothings*?

Comment: I'd be more interested in knowing what a _makeout session_ was.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: I'm wondering on those lines too.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but perhaps having breadcrumbs thrown is a less-offensive version of having the old-fashioned bucket of water thrown over you.

Comment: @BarrieEngland It's been a while since I was a young person living in the UK, but back then they called it *snogging*.

Comment: @Marcus_33. Oh, is that all?

Comment: Maybe the breadcrumbs are coz you're acting like a pigeon? Normally "breadcrumbs" would refer to hints or clues, like a breadcrumb trail, but I don't see how that fits here.

Answer (score 3):

*Booping noses* means to rub together your noses as a sign of affection.

And *sweet nothings* are the meaningless sweet words of affection and love  you'd say to your lover.

This sentence tries to say that if you are a couple who does that in a public place to the extent of making others uncomfortable, then probably you deserve to be ridiculed.

**Edit:**

@Inglish Teeture is right about the exact meaning of "you deserve to get breadcrumbs thrown at you". That meaning somehow didn't occur to me :)

Answer (score -1):

From what I discovered, *throw breadcrumbs at someone* could mean *breaking up* with your partner but still staying in touch as friends just in case you feel later that the decision to break up was uncalled for or otherwise, you can be partners again. [(Source)](http://www.loveshack.org/forums/breaking-up-reconciliation-coping/breaks-breaking-up/301440-why-do-dumpers-throw-us-breadcrumbs-any-thoughts)

In this context, however, it could simply mean 'the couple deserves *breaking up* because they are ignoring certain decency by displaying affection in public'. As far as *booping noses* and *sweet nothings* are concerned, @Sachin has explained well in his answer.